# Getting a python3: can't open file and Errno 2 Error after code successfully running on iMac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am a beginner coder who is moving from pycharm over to sublime text. From what I understand you can run programs in the command line or in terminal and I want to make sure I can do both. When I try to run my file by inputting "python 3&5Multiples.py" it runs the program and outputs this response. Ignore the first line as that is my input, I included it because it may be helpful to understand what is going on.

```
MyiMac-iMac:py ianbridges$ python 3&5Multiples.py
[1] 71175
-bash: 5Multiples.py: command not found
MyiMac-iMac:py ianbridges$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: can't open file '3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I make it so this text never appears and I just get the output of the program? Thanks!

Comment: `&` is a special shell character.  Rename your python script so it doesn't have that in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your shell command, anything after the `&` is considered as a separate command. So, in order to tell the shell that you want it to be considered entirely as one term, you must use **double-quotation marks**. So, you can edit your command like so:

```
$ python "3&5Multiples.py"
```

*PS: Don't include `$` in the command*